"Instantiate" function creates an extra object in the center of the scene
I attached this script to circle object and after run program on the scene there are two squares: one near my object(These are exactly the coordinates I set) and other in the center of the scene. Why other square appear in the center of the scene?
enter image description here
I have only 2 lines of  code in the void start:
   void Start() {
       Vector2 p = gameObject.transform.position;
       Instantiate(GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube), new Vector3(p.x + 0.5f * 0.86f, p.y - 0.5f * 0.5f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
   }


Id guess that the extra is already in your scene

If i comment this line then there isnt any extra

When i replace 'GameObject.CreatePrimitive(...) with my prefab problem is solved

As you already noticed in your comment, GameObject.CreatePrimitive:

Creates a GameObject with a primitive mesh renderer and appropriate collider.
Unity - Scripting API: GameObject.CreatePrimitive

So CreatePrimitive creates the object at (0,0,0), and the Instantiate call clones that object. Resulting in the two GameObjects you see, one at the world origin, and one at the correct position.
Simply removing the Instantiate call and modifying the newly created primitive fixes this:
void Start() {
    Vector2 p = gameObject.transform.position;
    GameObject newObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    newObject.transform.position = new Vector3(p.x + 0.5f * 0.86f, p.y - 0.5f * 0.5f, 0);
}

